# How to implement an asynchronous pipeline with queue

Tags: asynchronous-processing

Assume I have three tasks that must be performed in order:

```
Do[
    productA = TaskA[taskId];   (*consumes disk I/O*)
    productB = TaskB[productA]; (*consumes CPU*)
    TaskC[productB],            (*consumes network bandwidth*)
{taskId,10000}]
```

The three tasks above involve usage of different resources. For example, `TaskA` imports an image file from disk. `TaskB` performs some data augmentation via image processing. `TaskC` sends augmented data to another node via WSTP on TCP.

I would like to improve performance by making a *asynchronous pipeline*. That is, starting three threads for each task. Each task puts/retrieves intermediate results to/from a queue with fixed size.

```
(*hypothetical code*)
queueAB = MakeQueue[16];
queueBC = MakeQueue[16];
taskA = MakeThread[
    Do[
        With[{productA=TaskA[taskId]},EnQueue[queueAB, productA]];
        EnQueue[queueAB, $TaskEnded],
{taskId, 10000}]
];
taskB = MakeThread[
Module[{productA},
    While[True,
        productA = DeQueue[queueAB];
        If[productA === $TaskEnded,
                EnQueue[queueBC, $TaskEnded];
            Break[],
            EnQueue[queueBC, TaskB[productA]]
        ]
    ]
]
];
taskC = MakeThread[
Module[{productB},
    While[True,
        productB = DeQueue[queueBC];
        If[productB === $TaskEnded,
                Break[],
                TaskC[productB]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
ParallelRunThread[{taskA, taskB, taskC}]
```

How to implement the above pipeline?

Comment: Perhaps the Channel-based communication framework would fit, see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Channel-BasedCommunication.html